# Should I catch all exceptions or just SQLException when closing JDBC resources on a finally block?

Tags: java, exception, jdbc

Should I catch all exceptions (catch Throwable) when closing a resource like a JDBC resource (like a database connection) in a finally block (like the Spring Framework does [org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.closeConnection(Connection con)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/support/JdbcUtils.java) ) or should I only catch SQLException and let any other unchecked exception thrown from close() confuse the original caller by masking an exception in the try section or throwing an exception when everything in my code went OK, instead of just logging that JDBC driver exception like the Spring Framework does?

Comment: *"confuse the original caller by masking..."* - that does not look like a good plan. But really, when closing an SQL connection, the only logical error you may get is a direct SQLException, or something that was caused by it. So yes, just like Spring does, you should catch all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found out that the most sensible thing to do is to catch any exception when closing resources as you do not want your method to throw when the close throws an exception. [Spring Framework JdbcUtils](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/support/JdbcUtils.java) does the right thing. Some amateur programmers think that Errors are such grave Exceptions that should shutdown everything, but if you are running in servlet context these Errors will not shut down the application server see, for example, [Tomcat StandardWrapperValve](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardWrapperValve.java), so you should do the same and not let any Error when closing a resource make your method fail.

Comment: 1. You should definitely downtone the answer. 2. Here is a better handling for an Error than swallowing it: you restart the server. Ruby even adopted it as a memory management technique.p :D 3. If JDK references, situation examples and a hundred-upvoted answers don't persuade you, then what will?

Comment: @VictorSergienko You should fill a bug report at application servers (like Tomcat) and frameworks like Spring if you think that is what should be done.

Comment: I think this should be done in a very special cases, which I describe clearly in my answer, with the reasons for that. I advice you to re-read it, and to answer my arguments, particularly, how do you handle `OutOfMemoryError`, in favor of your application exception. This is how you have a professional discussion, and not a name-calling contest.

Comment: @VictorSergienko Just, write a servlet that throws an OutOfMemoryError. You will see that the application server will not crash. That is the good thing about being able to catch Errors like OutOfMemoryError as it allows applications to recover gracefully without crashing.

Comment: 1. If I just write `throw new OutOfMemoryError()`, yes. But normally `OutOfMemoryError` happens when, you know, a process is out of virtual memory. There is no recovery from it, unless you can release a massive amount of memory through a native call, or control multiple security domain in JVM, an shut down some of them. In normal applications, if you catch it, another one will happen soon, and your process is done for. 2. Are we talking about writing an application server or a Spring internals? That Wikipedia example is likely to end up in a generic user application.

Comment: @VictorSergienko When using an application server sometimes someone will request a bigger than usual report, when that request fails with OutOfMemoryError you do not want to crash the application server but log the error so that component can be fixed without bridging down the application server. The memory will be automatically be freed by Java garbage collector so that the rest of the application can continue working.

Comment: 1. This can happen, but the other cases also can. You have no right to assume the scenario you wish for. 2. Do you have something to handle `VirtualMachineError`?

Comment: VirtualMachineError will be handled just like OutOfMemoryError the application can continue working after freeing some resources. If the JVM were corrupted the sensible thing would be to crash the JVM, not to throw an exception.

Comment: Basically, you're saying "I can imagine the case when it will be alright, so I'll ignore the exception."

Answer (score 1):

Please note that Spring has serious excuses to do so:

- Spring is a "very special application" (as opposed to [reasonable application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)). It is a framework used in thousands of companies with a hundreds of JDBC implementations, and it needs to stand no matter what bugs they have.
- They specifically explain the reason for catching Throwable in a comment: `"// We don't trust the JDBC driver: It might throw RuntimeException or Error.`". You add a comment to a code when you do something that needs explanations, in this case - violating best practices.
- This code has to deal with hundreds of JDBC driver versions, lots of which use native code and can produce exotic errors.
- I believe, that Spring's exception handler is carefully hand-crafted not to invoke any memory allocation, even not a single new `String`, and to fulfill some more strict restrictions. Otherwise, it won't survive catching an `OutOfMemoryError` or `VirtualMachineError`.

Don't catch `Throwable`. `Error`, its subclass, says: "[An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)"

Moreover, it's even not normally reasonable to catch an `Exception`. Even if `close()` threw, for example, an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, you want to announce this as loud as possible to your team, your customer and his SE, for all of them should know that the JDBC driver cannot be trusted. `close()` [is only allowed to throw SQLException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close()), period.

Because, well, database is their main asset, and we NEED a working drivers.

Only as a last resort, like in this Spring example, when you KNOW you will be working with faulty drivers, this is acceptable.

Comment: Of course drivers should not throw on close, but if they do, the exception should not mask the original exception. When close throws an exception you should log a warning but not throw that exception to the caller, possibly masking the original exception.

Comment: It's a valid point - you will have to mask one of the two, unless you create an own "wrapper for two exceptions" class. Which one? Userspace exception or a JDBC contract violation? As for me, the latter is much more severe, even if it's just a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: The point "Don't catch `Throwable`" stands. You're going to handle `Error`? To preserve a userspace exception, when whole system is falling apart? Seriously?

Comment: It is a terrible idea to throw an exception when everything went OK, but a resource throws an exception on close for any reason. You log the error.

Comment: There are many professionally developed software that catches Throwable you should read good code. For example: https://github.com/apache/tomcat/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22catch+%28Throwable%22 or https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22catch+%28Throwable%22

Comment: Are you using Apache Tomcat or Spring Framework? If you are using them, you should either stop using these "broken" software components or start your crusade to "fix" them, just publish some bug reports and you will learn why Throwable should be catched in these cases.

Comment: Sorry, the only reason you mentioned is "Frameworks do that". I think I already answered that in the answer. Do you have others?

Comment: I am sorry but your arguments are bogus. Do you still think Spring Framework and Tomcat are buggy. Will you fill bugs for them?

Comment: I think they are a special case and they know very well what they do, which is not what is recommended in general case. I see no point in further discussion now. Let's continue it when your answer has 5 more upvotes than mine. Please don't touch Wikipedia till then.

Comment: If catching Throwable when closing JDBC resources is a special case where catching Throwable is OK, then you are supporting my point.

Comment: I think my explanations are bogus to you because you're too emotional when reading it. I have the impression that you only read 25% of it. Please go through all the bullet points... in a week. That's what I will do.